# Issue while using Except Extension Method

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

What is the problem with the code below?

```
var newContextElementCollection = new List<NewContextElements>();  
var res = from eleCollection in newContextElementCollection                     
          where eleCollection.Property.Except(new List<string> { "Password", "Some Other Value" })
          select eleCollection;
```

The `NewContextElementCollection` class:

```
public class NewContextElements
{
    public string Property { get; set; }    
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Instance argument: cannot convert from 'string' to 
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'
>   Error 2   'string' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension
>    method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Except(System.Linq.IQueryable,
>
> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Property` is a string, not an `IEnumerable<string>`, which is what your `Except` clause can work on.

```
var res= from eleCollection in newContextElementCollection
     where eleCollection.Property !=  "Password"
     select eleCollection;
```

Comment: That is correct. Actually the exclude list will be a collection and not a scalar item. Like new List<string> { "Password","Some other value" }. How to handle this?

Comment: The example you shown has similar Entity type. In my case, it is however different. In such a case it won't fit (i think so)

Comment: @user1323981: then the problem is that `Except` can not serve as a predicate, because is does not return a boolean. You can use it in a select clause, `select eleCollection.Property.Except...`

Answer (score 0):

```
var excluded = new List<string> { "Password","Some Other Value" };
var res = newContextElementCollection.Where(m => !excluded.Contains(m.Property));
```